# How to redirect to login page when user not loggedin on a particular page

Tags: plugin-development, redirect

In my plugin there are many pages.  I want to redirect to a login page if the user is not loggedin on a particular page.  I used below code, but it redirect to login page on all pages.  I want to specific page only.

```
<?php
class Coupon {
  private static $instance = null;

  private function __construct(){
    add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'add_shortcodes' ));
    add_action( 'template_redirect', array(&$this, 'redirect_user' ));
  }

  public static function get_instance(){
    if(!self::$instance){
      self::$instance = new Coupon();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  function add_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'coupon-form', array(&$this,'coupon_form' ));
  }

  function redirect_user() {
    Log::d("redirected");
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page( 'login' ) ) {
      wp_redirect( Login::url() );
      exit;
    }
  }
  
  function coupon_form() {
    ob_start();
      ?>
          <div class="coupon_widget_form">
              <form id="coupon_form" name="coupon_form" method="post" action="">
                  <div>
                      <label for="coupon">Coupon</label>
                      <input type="text" id="coupon" value="YZ7U PQnm EAQ3" size="25" name="coupon" />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                      <input type="submit" name="coupon_submit" value="Redeem"/>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      <?php
      return ob_get_clean();
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You didn't mentioned the particular page in your code. There should be a list of page or a page within your condition. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you just need to change the `if` in your `redirect_user()` function to:

```php
// List of Page slugs of the particular pages in question.
$pages = array( 'page-slug', 'another-slug', 'etc-etc' );
// .. or specify a list of Page IDs: array( 1, 2, 3, ... )

// Redirect only if the current Page's slug (or ID) is within the above list.
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( $pages ) ) {
    wp_redirect( Login::url() );
    exit;
}
```

But of course, by "page", I presumed you meant a Page, i.e. post of the `page` type?

And if that's not the case, i.e. you're (also) referring to other WordPress pages like CPT and term archives, then you can check the [conditional tags here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) and just use the one(s) that match your particular pages ([`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) is one of those conditional tags). But the exact condition/logic will certainly depend on the type of pages in which the login redirection should be applied.

```php
// Example..
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && (
    is_page( array( 'foo', 'bar', 'etc-slug' ) ) || // check if it's one of the Pages
    is_singular( 'my-cpt' )                         // or a if it's any single CPT pages
) ) {
    wp_redirect( Login::url() );
    exit;
}
```